# how to resolve error : TF400425:

Tags: tfs

When I am merging from one branch to another branch. getting the error
TF400425: Some items under the source branch $A\B were not branched or merged because user_abcd does not have Read permission for those items.

Any idea, what is the issue and how to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to get an administrator to do the merge as there is something in there that you do not have permission to.

This is the downside of setting explicit permissions.

Comment: I am getting only for the few files , along this error I am getting one more error.TF14121: The changes previously made to branch\filename. that have not been merged will be discarded by merging 

the deletion of branch\filename

Comment: You do not have permission to those files